# javascript redirect form working in Chrome/Safari, but nor Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, redirect, passwords

I am trying to create a redirect after visitor inputs an access code for a promotional campaign. It works fine in OS X Chrome & Safari and Windows Chrome, but not OS X Firefox or Windows IE & Firefox.

Website is located at https://www.preciousmetals.com/offer12

I have this script in the head…

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkCode() {
        if (this.password.value.toLowerCase() == 'AAL1012'.toLowerCase()) { 
            window.location='https://www.preciousmetals.com/special-offer-12.html'; 
        } 
        else { 
            alert('Wrong Access Code!'); 
        } 
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

And this in the body…

```
<form onsubmit="return checkCode()">
                                <h3 style="text-align: center;">
                                    Enter Access Code To Proceed
                                </h3>
                                <div style="text-align: center;">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" />
                                    <input  type="submit" value="Proceed"  />
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not validate a password with javascript like that. It's a big security issue.

If you want to do it anyway try this:

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">
    Enter Access Code To Proceed
</h3>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <button onClick="checkCode();return false;" type="button">Proceed</button>
</div>
```

Notice that I removed the form and replaced the button code

Comment: I know, but there's not really a security factor in this use case. They are just tracking campaign response for the access code.

This works great! Thanks!